# What are these dark spots in my pictures?

Tags: spots

I've been seeing these dark spots in my pictures. They appear a lot more on some pictures than others, but they are in the same place in the image and independent of the lens being used. Is this dust? I've also heard that you can get oil spots on the sensor.

The image is from a Nikon D7000.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since they are always in the same place, this points to the presence of dust in the camera (and not in the lens). There are [several](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-the-sensor-on-a-digital-slr) [questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-properly-clean-a-camera) on this site which explain how to clean the camera by yourself. Obviously, if you feel uncomfortable doing it, [you can have it cleaned by a camera lab](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9541/should-i-clean-my-camera-sensor-myself-or-take-it-to-a-professional).

To some degree it is possible to remove these speck via software, when processing the (raw) file: but this is obviously going to work only to some extent, if you have a lot of dust.

Comment: Is there a reason they show up much stronger some times and not at all other times? I think they appear much stronger when using a smaller aperture (or potentially taking a picture of something brighter).

Comment: Try taking an out of focus picture of a bright object (like the sky) at a smalla aperture. That should give a confirmation. HAve you read the links that I posted?

Comment: yes thank you I think what I'm really trying to find out is if this is dust (which would be my fault) or oil drops (which may be covered by my warranty?).

Comment: @Freed: when the aperture is smaller, the light outlining the dust is more parallel, making them sharper. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/why-use-a-small-aperture-when-trying-to-see-sensor-dust